# looking for a cron / scheduler job on my production server

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

ON my production server every saturday weekly emailer task starts and we all start getting emails. However I am not able to figure out where this cron job is set on my server or in my php joomla code.

I have checked crontab -e output and its like as below:

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
#
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command
```

as everything here is commneted I presume there is cron job placed.

Please let me know what all should I look into so that I can get to know how this weekly emailer is being triggered. Any kind of help is appreciated !!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Joomla, so it could be in there. However, make sure that you check all users for cron entries, such as root, or perhaps you have an emailer user.

Comment: can you tell me the command to check that.. Does crontab -e list for a specific user only?

Answer (score 2):

Got it by running the below script:

for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do crontab -u $user -l; done

It showed all the cron jobs listed by all users